# Getting a class property from a data bound treeview on treeviewitem click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, treeviewitem

I'm having a problem, and no matter how much surfing stackoverflow and other parts of the internet I can't seem to get a right answer. I have a treeview which is bound to a `List<Category>` and my `Category` class is as below;

```
public class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public dynamic SearchEngine { get; set; }
}

public class SearchEngine
{
    public virtual string IKey { get; set; }
    public virtual string IValue { get; set; }
    public virtual string icon { get; set; }
}
```

Now, the TreeView is using a custom template which is looking like this;

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=childrenDataTemplate}">
        <Border BorderThickness="0" Margin="5">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </Border>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"/>
            </Style>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>

<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

As you can see I've got `TreeViewItemSelected` bound in my TreeView object, and I'm able to alert a messagebox when selection is changed. I would like to get `IValue` on selection and pass it to another function to do something with. I've looked into SelectedItem but can't seem to find a way to get to the underlying data source.

Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: What about `casting`? If you know the type of the underlying item data, just cast it to that type.

Comment: @KingKing Yeah turned out to work, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
void HandleSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tvi = e.Source as TreeViewItem;
        var category = tvi.DataContext as Category;
        ...
    }
```

Comment: This worked, although I had to use `e.OriginalSource` instead, accepting as answer, thanks.